# ko observablearray: Difference between push and assigning directly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observablearray defined as:

```
model.permitList = ko.observableArray([]);
```

I am initializing it with an array of objects. There is a difference when I do this

```
  model.permitList (arrayOfObjects)
```

vs.

when I do this

```
  for(var i=0; i<arrayOfObjects.length; i++ ){
    model.permitList().push(arrayOfObjects(i));
  }
```

I know there is a difference because when I try to display the data in a table in my view using

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.permitList">
```

only the first method works.

Does anybody know the difference between the two methods? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With your 2nd method, you are getting the values with an actual `Array`, not the `ObservableArray`.

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayOfObjects.length; i++ ){
  model.permitList.push(arrayOfObjects(i));
}
```

This will mutate the observable array.

When you do `model.permitList()` returns a native `Array` object with each of the values. When you call `.push` on that, it modifies that array. `model.permitList` however is a Knockout object.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `model.permitList()`, its like executing a getter function to get the value. In your case the returned value is a native array on which you `.push` your values. This will result in a native array and not observableArray. For knockout view bindings to work and value changes to reflect you need an `observableArray`, which can only be done when you use your variable like a setter as `model.permitList (arrayOfObjects)`

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped me clear the confusion for the most part.